# Retrofit in Android- POST

Tags: android, eclipse, post, retrofit

as I can receive data with retrofit on android, I am new to android programming, add the library, but not how to make the request, I need help, and create the interface follows.

1.interface Constants:

```
public interface Constants {
    String URL = "http://mydress.com/api/signin/signin.php";
}
```

2.interface LoginRetrofit:

```
public interface LoginRetrofit {



    @POST(Constants.URL)
    void getUser(@Body JSONObject searchstring, Callback<JSONObject> callBack);

}
```

as I make the request for the data???

Answer (score 0):

Constants.class:

```
public interface Constants {
    String URL = "/api/signin/signin.php";
}
```

LoginRetrofit.class:

```
public interface LoginRetrofit {

    @POST(Constants.URL)
    void getUser(@Body JSONObject searchstring, Callback<JSONObject> callBack);

}
```

The class where you want to call this API method:

```
//Build RestAdapter
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("http://mydress.com")
    .build();

//Create API service
LoginRetrofit service = restAdapter.create(LoginRetrofit.class);

//Invoke method. Parameters must be defined earlier of course
service.getUser(searchstring, callBack);
```

http://square.github.io/retrofit/